# creating a mandatory selection popup before a web page execution

Tags: php, javascript, html

Is their a way that when when a particular web page is opened a pop-up appears and until I select some value from that pop-up I cant do ant thing in the background web page and also that the execution of this web page halts until pop-up is their.
I found this :

```
win2 = window.open("popup_choose_template.html", "Window2", "width=310,height=600,scrollbars=yes");
```

but its like just another web page which can be closed or just ignored.
what should be a better way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [jQueryUI with Modal Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation):

eg:

```
$( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
    height:140,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Ok": function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
});
```

It disables all background page and forces user to do something.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for you would probably to use JQuery UI and use the Dialog control with modal set to true. This will display a popup window with the background darkened and disabled.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-modal

Otherwise if you want to do it by hand, you add a 100% width and height div, absolute positioned with black background color, partial transparency & a higher z-index than the rest of the page. append this div to body, and make sure your pop up has an even higher z-index than the blackout div

**Edit**

you need a fixed position div not absolute... like this:

```
<div id="blackout" style="position:fixed; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:100; background-color:black; opacity:0.5;"></div>
```

This assumes all your normal page elements have a z-index below 100 and you give your popup a z-index above 100. Append to body with the js popup function, and then remove upon satisfactory selection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use modal panel kind of thing.

Like [jQuery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal)